# How to enroll in Google Play's 15% service fee?

Tags: android, google-play

In google play it is written that
"Starting on July 1, 2021, Google reduces the service fee to 15% for the first $1M"

How can I enroll 15% service fee in google play?

Comment: I think you are enrolled by default in this service fee package. And again you will be automatically enrolled in the other package if your app passed through the $1M barrier.

Comment: Note, just putting your quote into Google search brings up a link to the Google support page with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 15% service fee enrolment is not automatic. Go into your Play Console, section "Associated developer account". From that, follow the procedure of creating an "Account Group" and tell them if you have "ADAs", Associated developer accounts.

The concepts of ADAs might be a bit complex at first sight but if you're a single developer it is quite straightforward. From the guide:

> Many developers only own a single Developer Account, in which case
> they will not have ADAs. If you only own a single Developer Account,
> you will still need to create an Account Group for the single account
> you own.

Once you completed the procedure, a new button appears and by clicking it you can enrol to the program.

As reported by @Morrison Chang, [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10632485) and [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10627869#account_group_create) are good starting points if you need further information.